# Implicit ref-cursors not being closed in ODP.net 12c release 2

Tags: odp.net, oracle12c, ora-01000

I'm porting a .net application from SqlServer to Oracle 12c.
I'm using the unmanaged 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) client to access the database.

Oracle 12c introduced the DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cur) function that allows me to reuse the .net code as it is without having to add specific output parameters to the ado.net commands. 
This is a snippet of what my code looks like:

```
using (var command = CreateCommand("uspGetAllNumericUnits", CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            using (var connectionScope = command.Connection.CreateConnectionScope())
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ....
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The uspGetAllNumericUnits stored procedure is simply like:

```
PROCEDURE uspGetAllNumericUnits_RPT
AS
  cv_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cv_1 FOR
      SELECT * FROM NumericUnit;

  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cv_1);
END;
```

I believe I properly dispose the dbReader and the dbCommand and the connection is closed and disposed as well by the connectionScope.
However, if I check the  v$open_cursor view on the server, I see that a cursor for "SELECT * FROM NumericUnit;" remains open. 
I use connection pooling, if I disable it (which I do not want to do) the cursor gets correctly closed as the connectionScope gets disposed.

My issue is that I have many ado.net calls like this one, and I quickly reach the max allowed cursor limit per session and an ORA-01000 error is raised.

If I use the old Oracle 11g approach, returning the resultset cursor as an output parameter and not using the DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cv_1) function, the cursor gets correctly closed as the connectionScope is disposed regardless connection pooling or not.

Are there some extra objects I need to dispose the close the implicit ref-cursors? Is this a known ODAC 12cR2 bug?
The introduction of DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cv_1) makes the porting from SqlServer to Oracle way easier than having to add output parameters almost everywhere, but I do not want to get rid of connection pools.

Comment: Where are the `close` calls?  I'd expect that you'd have a call to `reader.close()` for example.

Comment: `reader.close()` should be called within  `reader.Dispose()`  automatically called at the end ot the `using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())` block.

Comment: By default, statement caching is also on. I am not sure that impacts your situation since this is a stored procedure but you might try disabling it (and then restarting your connection pool).

Comment: I disabled statement caching adding these parameters to the connection string `Statement Cache Size=0;Self Tuning=false`, (restarted IIS to be sure the connection pool was wiped out), but nothing changed.

Comment: I noticed that if I replace in my code
`using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())` with
`command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                    using (var reader = ((OracleCommand)command).ImplicitRefCursors[0].GetDataReader())`

the cursor gets correctly closed on the server when the connectionScope ends.  
(From Oracle documentation it seems that `command.ImplicitRefCursors` gets filled up only when `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`is called).